# TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'set'

Tags: ember.js

once a certain process is done I need to set a boolean to true in order to update the template.

I can easily get the object, but setting a property seems to be more difficult. What I use to get the object is

```
var found = self.get('content').findProperty('id', self.datasetid);
```

If I do that in the chrome console I can clearly see that I get an ember object back:

```
Object {id: 1, active: true}
__ember1364221685101_meta: Meta
active: true
get data_set: function () {
id: 1
set data_set: function (value) {
__proto__: Object
```

When I do:

```
found.set('data_set.fully_geocoded', true);
```

I do get the error mentioned in title. I've tried as many different flavours as I could think of, but all with the same result.

Could somebody shine a light on this?

Comment: Have you tried `found.get('data_set').fully_geocoded = true;`?

Comment: @Thomas more or less the same result, TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'get'. I also believe that the binding system is not triggered when I don't do a 'set' on the property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `Object` isn't an instance of Ember.Object, but the base Javascript class `Object`, so it won't have a `get` and `set` method.

You can get much of the same functionality by using `Ember.get` and `Ember.set` directly, passing in the object, as such:

```
Ember.set(found, 'data_set.fully_geocoded', true)
Ember.get(found, 'data_set.fully_geocoded')
```

Computed properties and observers can also fire based on using `Ember.set` this way.

Comment: This seems to trigger the observers only ones... I'm really confused.